# Rails ActiveRecord mixed conditions of where and where.not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im trying to select a subset of records from my database using Rails 4.1.8 and Ruby 2.1.5 with ActiveRecord. But the result includes the records that I'm trying to omit with the where.not clause. The resulting sql is also noted below. It looks to me that the sql for the where.not clause is either being ignored or is incorrect. What is the proper way to do this?

```
class TablesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tables = Table.all.order("fil ASC").where(object: ['REP', 'CPT']).where.not(srcmbr: 'A*' )
  end

end
```

Result

```
Table Load (7.3ms)  SELECT inputfile.* FROM inputfile  WHERE inputfile.object IN ('REP', 'CPT') AND (inputfile.srcmbr != 'A*') ORDER BY fil ASC
  Rendered tables/index.html.erb within layouts/application (709.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 912ms (Views: 882.4ms | ActiveRecord: 20.4ms)
```

Comment: Does `A*` represent pattern mathing? If so, try: `.where('srcmbr NOT LIKE ?', 'A%')`

Comment: Just a note: `Table.where(object: ['REP', 'CPT']).where.not(srcmbr: 'A*' ).order(fil: :asc)`. What is wrong with the query anyway? Seems legit.

Comment: The items matching 'A*' are showing up in the result.

Comment: @maicher, thanks for the answer. If you will post it, I'll accept it.

Comment: @BobNicholson ok. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `A*` represent pattern mathing? If so, try:

```
.where('srcmbr NOT LIKE ?', 'A%')
```

Answer (score 0):

.where('srcmbr NOT LIKE ?', 'A%')

This solved my problem.

Comment: This was suggested by @maicher. Appropriate course of action would be to ask him to post the answer and then accept it.

Comment: I would like to have done that but I'm not sure why he did not post the answer.